# buttons in Toolbar are not visible in storyboard (xcode6)

Tags: storyboard, xcode6, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I have a toolBar with uiButtonItem and some flexible/fixed space item in my storyBoard. 
with xcode6 they are no more visible, I can still see the edge when switching  between buttons in view inspector but they are not visible. I tried to change button tint/ background but they are still not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out that in the Simulated Metric of the ViewController the bottomBar was not set to inferred.
I reset it to inferred and all ButtonItems are now shown exactly as before.

Comment: just want to thank you for answring your own question. it helped me!